# Verb plus adjective in adjective phrase

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis, direct-objects

> The would make me feel alive.

Is there an elipsis with 'to' infinitive marker that not displayed before feel? Is there an adjective phrase 'feel alive' with adjective head? Is the 'to feel alive' a direct object because it's an answer of 'What?' question?

,without ellipsis

> They would make me to feel alive human.

Is there a noun phrase 'feel alive human'? Is the 'to' a preposition and 'feel alive human' a prepositional object here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no omitted **to**, and it would be grammatically incorrect to include one. Some grammatical constructions require an infinitive with **to**: others require a [bare infinitive](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/) (an infinitive without to). According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make), the verb **make** meaning **cause** requires a bare infinitive:

> make verb (CAUSE)
>   B1 [ T ]
>   to cause something:
>   ...
>   [ + infinitive without to ] The wind is making my eyes water.

No, the phrase 'alive human' is not correct. **Alive** is an unusual adjective- see [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alive), and **human** in this context must also be and adjective. **feel alive**, as in the question before you edited it, is fine. If you wanted to add human, you would have to add an **and**

> They would make me feel alive **and** human

Comment: Does the predicator include 'feel'?

Comment: Yes. A predicate must include a verb, and in this case it's **feel**.

Comment: And is 'me' a direct object and 'alive' an indirect object?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, **alive** is an adjective- a predicate adjective. Predicate adjectives are used with linking verbs like **feel**. **me** is the object of **make** and also the subject of the predicate clause. Read a brief description of predicates here https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/predicate.htm  or download the Oxford Guide to English Grammar from here: https://archive.org/details/OxfordGuideToEnglishGrammar_201701/mode/2up